# PHP RSS Feed Crawler

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, rss

I wanna build a RSS Feed Crawler for my website. Though im not quite sure, how to begin this. How can my Crawler identify the RSS feed? Is there any thing I can crawl for, which every RSS reader has?
I don't need any code, just some help for my brain to understand what I have to create.

Thanks in before!

Greetings

Xatenev

Comment: Check https://superfeedr.com if you don't feel like re-inventing the wheel :)

Comment: Hey, it seems very cool, but what can I do with that? :P It seems like a huge database for feeds, where i (possibly) get a lot of RSS feeds. Is that correct?^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be possible if your crawler scans all links and opens each page at least one time to look for the text `<rss version="2.0">`. From what I understand, every RSS feed should contain this line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
 <title>RSS Title</title>
 <description>This is an example of an RSS feed</description>
 <link>http://www.someexamplerssdomain.com/main.html</link>
 <lastBuildDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2010 00:01:00 +0000 </lastBuildDate>
 <pubDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000 </pubDate>
 <ttl>1800</ttl>

 <item>
  <title>Example entry</title>
  <description>Here is some text containing an interesting description.</description>
  <link>http://www.wikipedia.org/</link>
  <guid>unique string per item</guid>
  <pubDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2009 16:20:00 +0000 </pubDate>
 </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

If you're going to use PHP, I have very positive experiences with SimpleXML which is built in PHP.

P.S. Xatenev you're welcome ;)

Comment: And how can I actually crawl for those RSS feeds? How can my crawler identify those, and give me the data back, which I need?

Comment: I don't know if you have much experience with regular expressions, I think that's the way to go.

Comment: I know about regular expressions, but I mean a crawler for example, just goes on a website and picks up all links, then he continues crawling on the other website. How can i pick up all RSS feeds on the website? Those links are easy found from the source code, can I find RSS feeds from the source code aswell?

Comment: Could you clarify that some more? I think it would be possible if your crawler scans all links and opens each page at least one time to look for the text "<rss version="2.0">". From what I understand, every RSS feed should contain this line.

Comment: Ah thats what i wanted to know, very cool, thank you! Thanks for the good explanation :).